# Rootless cgexec with cgroups v2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: cgroups

On operating systems which use cgroups v2, such as Ubuntu 22.04, I am unable to 'cgexec' any process without being root. This type of code used to work fine. I tried it on a recent redhat release and had similar problems.

For example:

```
$ sudo cgcreate -t caj:caj -a caj:caj -g memory:qqq
[sudo] password for caj:
$ cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
cgroup change of group failed
$ sudo cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
<files ...>
```

Comment: I realise mentioning "Ubuntu 22.04" is very concrete, but I'm not sure if this is a general problem, or an ubuntu-specific problem.

Comment: I also meet the same problem in Fedora 37. So it seems like an issue of cgroups v2. Maybe systemd is relevant?